# Problems with classes / methods

Tags: java, class, methods

So I have this code I'm working on for my AP computer science class and I'm getting tons of errors when I compile even though when I look at it, it looks fine and everything is in order. All the errors are coming from my myClock class and RepairShop class.

```
public class APCS_104_Time {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        tester tester = new tester();
    }
}

    class myClock {

    private int minute;
    private int hour;

    public myClock() {
        hour = 2;
        minute = 3;
    }

    public myClock(int minute, int hour) {

        public int getHour() {
            hour = IO.getInt("Enter the hour");
            return hour;
        }

        public int getMinute() {
            minute = IO.getInt("Enter the minute");
            return minute;
        }

        public void int setMinute(int minute) {
            this.minute = minute;
        }

        public void int setHour(int hour) {
            this.hour = hour;
        }

        public String toString() {
            if (minute < 10) {
                return (hour + ":0" + minute);
            }
            else {
                return (hour + ":" + minute); 
            }
        }
    }
}

class RepairShop {

    public void int springForward(myClock time) {
        hour++;
    }

    public void int resetClock(myClock time) {
        hour = 2;
        minute = 3;
    }

    public int cloneClock(myClock time) {

        myClock copy = myClock myClock.clone();
        return myClock;
    }
}

class Tester { 

    Tester() {

        myClock time = new myClock();

        System.out.printf("The time is: " + myClock(2, 20));
    }
}
```

Error messages include:

```
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:38: error: illegal start of expression
        public void int setMinute(int minute) {
        ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:38: error: illegal start of expression
        public void int setMinute(int minute) {
               ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:38: error: ';' expected
        public void int setMinute(int minute) {
                   ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:38: error: '.class' expected
        public void int setMinute(int minute) {
                                      ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:38: error: ';' expected
        public void int setMinute(int minute) {
                                            ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:42: error: illegal start of expression
        public void int setHour(int hour) {
        ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:42: error: illegal start of expression
        public void int setHour(int hour) {
               ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:42: error: ';' expected
        public void int setHour(int hour) {
                   ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:42: error: '.class' expected
        public void int setHour(int hour) {
                                    ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:42: error: ';' expected
        public void int setHour(int hour) {
                                        ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:46: error: illegal start of expression
        public String toString() {
        ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:46: error: ';' expected
        public String toString() {
                              ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:58: error: <identifier> expected
    public void int springForward(myClock time) {
               ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:58: error: '(' expected
    public void int springForward(myClock time) {
                ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:58: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public void int springForward(myClock time) {
                    ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:62: error: <identifier> expected
    public void int resetClock(myClock time) {
               ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:62: error: '(' expected
    public void int resetClock(myClock time) {
                ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:62: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public void int resetClock(myClock time) {
                    ^
C:\Users\Tom\Dropbox\Auriemma, Thomas\AP Comp Sci\Unit 1\APCS_104_Time.java:69: error: ';' expected
        myClock copy = myClock myClock.clone();
```

Comment: Posting some error messages could be helpful

Comment: Best to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32899386/edit) your question with errors

Comment: If you can, I suggest using an IDE, code assist, and syntax highlighting helps tremendously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things you need to fix:

First of all

```
//This myClock constructor can't contain other method!    
public myClock(int minute, int hour) {

            public int getHour() {
                hour = IO.getInt("Enter the hour");
                return hour;
            }

    ...
    }
```

Second thing is, the setter is `void`, can't be `void` and `int`, remove `int` out of these kind of method :

```
public void int setMinute(int minute) {
            this.minute = minute;
}
```

Third thing is, the hour is a property in `myClock` you can't use in other class:

```
private int hour;
```

The fourth point is you need to follow the convention. Class name must be Upper case first letter. For example `myClock` -> `MyClock`

Please also refer this to understand more about the class in Java:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html

After fixing all above points, I believe you can understand and fix your code. If not, just ping me.

Hope this help!